# If a class inherits a method does calling that method on that class point to the super class or does it make a local copy within the child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

Say I have Class A and Class B. Class B extends Class A. Class A has one method.

```
public class notimportant
 {
    public void one()
    {
    }
 }

public class A extends notimportant
{
    public void one()
    { 
        //assume there is a super class making this call legal which doesnt do anything
        super.one();
        System.out.println("blah");
    } 
}

public class B extends A
{
}
```

A var1 = new B();

if I call 'var1.one();' will the output end up being:

"blah"
"blah"

because it creates a local copy of 'one()' in Class B and then reads that which calls 'super()' which leads it up to method 'one()' in Class A OR does it just print

"blah"

because it knows to look directly at Class A

EDIT: Hope that is a lot more clear now.

Comment: The question would be better explained using actual code. Show us the structure you are having. Currently it's not very clear from your text.

Comment: I goes all the way to the top class, then cascades down...not a very technical answer, it's better to see it on code.

Comment: And what is that `method` before method name. There is no such modifier in Java. Also what is `S.O.Pln`? It takes mear 3 seconds to type `System.out.println`.

Comment: It would print twice, however your code has a semantic error in that you're not allowed to have spaces in method names

Comment: If the method is overwritten in the subclass, then only the subclass's method is called (unless inside it it has a call to super()). If the method is not overwritten in the subclass, then the superclass'es method is called.

Comment: you can't call super.one() unless the super class has a method named one... When you call super.xxx that means you want the superclasses version of that method (it won't call itself)

Comment: No no the method is inherited and there is no over-written copy. However the inherited method has a call to super.one() in it. Essentially it calls itself because it's simply a copy so it should double the output ya?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will follow the way you have it currently written:

> -> New object of class `B`
>
> -> Call method `One` on this object
>
> -> First line calls supermethod, proceed to execute it
>
> -> Second line prints out after that

Your code doesn't compile at all though, you might want to clear that up. What's keeping you from testing this yourself?

Here's the new situation as you described it. Everything still works as expected, you just add a layer.

```
public class C {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Inside C");
    }
}

public class B extends C {
    public void test() {
        super.test();
        System.out.println("Inside B");
    }
}

public class A extends B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A();
        obj.test();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Inside C
Inside B
```

Comment: I definitely could have tested it myself... for some reason thought there was some more conceptual under-the-hood of Java to the question. The code you typed up doesn't accurately represent my question though. Class A in this instance would not have a test() method but would simply inherit it from Class B, which would already have a call to super.test() in it.

Comment: @MilanNovaković: I have edited my post. Does this reflect your situation more accurately?

Comment: Yes!

Okay so conceptually speaking, there isn't a copy of an inherited method inside that subclass, it simply knows a reference and points to the super class?

Comment: Indeed. If you don't specify an override of a method of a superclass it and you call that method on your object, then it will invoke the first (only) method in its hierarchy that corresponds to that signature. The sub-subclass has no knowledge that this method is also defined in a class two levels higher, so it will always refer to its own superclass .

Comment: A little clarification on the latter part... say there's a subclass to class A that doesn't override the method test(). If I call test() on that subclass then the same output from above would be produced right?

Comment: Yes, it's the same output. You can put as many layers in there as you want, it will still take the first method with a fitting signature up its hierarchy. These are things you can test very easily yourself, I have even provided you the code. Or deduct it: if you create a subclass it can still access every method from `Object` right? Same principle.

Answer (score 1):

`super` means *your* superclass – it's resolved at compile-time.

It does not mean the immediate parent class of whatever the runtime type of `this` is.